# Gradle checkstyle plugin xml report

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

as i know checkstyle creates two types of report, xml and plain text. Which parameter i should update to make report as xml?

example xml output

```
java com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c docs/sun_checks.xml \
     -f xml -o build/checkstyle_errors.xml Check.java
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, answer found, create reportsDir property in checkstyle.

example

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.4'
    configFile = file('google_checks.xml');
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/checkstyle/")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding reportsDir worked for me, and it put the generated HTML reports in the build directory. Nice.